# Simple calendar - days + hours

Tags: php, datetime, date, loops

```
$columns = array('mon','thu','wed','tue', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun');
$num_cols = count($columns);
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
foreach($columns as $col)
{
   echo "<td>$col</td>";
   for($i=1;$i<20;$i++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    $datetime = new DateTime();
    for($j=0;$j<$num_cols;$j++){
        $datetime->modify('+30 minutes');

        echo '<td>' . $datetime->format('H:i:s') . '</td>';
    }

    echo "</tr>";
 }
}
echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";
```

How can i modify this for:

```
mon      |   thu     etc
10:10:10 | 10:10:10
10:40:10 | 10:40:10
11:10:10 | 11:10:10
etc
```

Now this bad working. I would like create simple calendar. This generated for me to many hours for one day.
Thanks for help!

Edit:
**If this is simply i can use only one loop for - with hours - without $columns. but how can i make it?**

i would like receive:

```
10:10:10 | 10:10:10 etc
10:40:10 | 10:40:10
11:10:10 | 11:10:10
etc
```

with **$datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')** :) i dont know how i can show this is columns - from top to down, not from left to right

Comment: If you are not going to modify the DOM, you need to change you logic and generate this table per row and not per column. - Iterate over the time, not the days.

Comment: Can you explain more your questions sincerely I don't get it

Comment: @Smamatti how can i make it? please give me example:)

Comment: @RageZ i would like make it same as in example table below text "How can i modify this for:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$columns = array('mon','thu','wed','tue', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun');
$num_cols = count($columns);
$col = 0;
$datetime = new DateTime();

echo "<table>"; // border=\"1\" for visible border

// Day header
echo "<tr>";
foreach($columns as $col) {
    echo "<td>$col</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";


// Times
for($i=0; $i<20; $i++) { // FIXME for more entries or other step width
    echo "<tr>";
    $datetime->modify('+30 minutes');

    for ($j=0; $j<$num_cols; $j++)
        echo '<td>' . $datetime->format('H:i:s') . '</td>';

    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

[image: Output]